# Массив в конце цикла undefined

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Есть массив items, с которым я работаю в цикле. В конце я вывожу console.log(items[a] + ' : ' + min);
min выводится нормально, items[a] выводится как undefined. Как решить проблему с выводом items[a]?

```
var items = [1, 2, 3];
for (var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) {
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(items[a]);
}, 0);
}
```

Comment: Может быть давайте локализуем проблему? ;) Как вам вот такой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/f8r2hgx9/1/ ?

Comment: Все равно не понял. Можно еще подсказку?

Comment: А это не подсказка. Это тонкий намек на то, что все лишнее, не относящееся к вопросу **надо из него выкинуть**.

Comment: Пример того, как можно упростить ваш код в вопросе, я привел в своем ответе.

Comment: Вставил ваш код вместо своего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле, единственная ваша проблема заключается в непонимании принципов работы асинхронного кода.

Для того, чтобы упростить объяснение, позволю себе использовать вместо вашей функции `request` вот такую асинхронную функцию:

```
var request = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
}
```

Тогда, отбросив весь тот код, что не относится к сути вопроса, я получаю вот такой тестовый сценарий:

```
var request = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
}

var items = [1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    request(function() {
        console.log(items[i]);
    });
}
```

Как вы можете догадаться, этот код три раза выведет `undefined` в консоль.

**В чем причина?**

Причина кроется в асинхронной природе функции `request`, которая выполняет callback *на следующем витке* [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9). По-факту, этот код будет выполняться вот в такой последовательности:

1. Инициализация `i` значением 0.
2. Вызов `request`, которая *откладывает выполнение* функции-аргумента.
3. Увеличение счетчика цикла (`i = 1`)
4. Вызов `request`, которая *откладывает выполнение* функции-аргумента.
5. Увеличение счетчика цикла (`i = 2`) и выход из цикла (`2 = items.length`).
6. Выполнение функции из п.2
7. Выполнение функции из п.4

А теперь самый интересный факт: на момент реального выполнения функции, переданной в `request`, поток выполнения программы уже дошел до конца цикла и переменная `i` имеет значение `2`! Вполне очевидно, что `items[2] == undefied`.

**Что с этим делать?**

Традиционным методом решения этой проблемы является создание [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) вокруг функции `request` с передачей переменной-счетчика:

```
var items = [1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    (function (counter) {
        request(function() {
            console.log(items[counter]);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

При этом, текущее значение переменной-счетчика сохраняется в локальной области видимости, образованной замыканием (через аргумент `counter`) и уже не зависит изменения переменной `i`.

А вот и [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqqrho66/1/).

Более современным способом решения, является использования [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) вместо `var`:

```
var items = [1, 2];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    request(function() {
        console.log(items[i]);
    });
}
```

Использование `let` в данном случае позволяет привязать значение переменной к локальной области видимости цикла `for`.

А вот и [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xzbwr38/).

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Использование let вместо var решило мою проблему полностью.